# Python Syntax Error with Dictionary

Tags: python, syntax

I am trying to do the following code:

```
while y < x:
    data_list[y].title = title
    data_list[y].link = link
    data_list[y].description = description
    story_list.update({title: link, description})
    y += 1
```

Where x is `len(data_list)` and y = 0 outside the loop.

When I try to run it, I get a syntax error for '}' only (not on the '{' bracket though) on the dictionary line for the update.  How can I fix the code so I don't get the syntax error and I can add this to the dictionary story_list?

Comment: `{title: link, description}` isn't a valid dict syntax. do you want to add 2 entries or just one?

Comment: I'm looking to add 2 entries with one index

Answer (score 0):

Or if a tuple, as in mu's answer isn't what you want to work with, why not make it another dictionary....

```
while y < x:
    data_list[y].title = title
    data_list[y].link = link
    data_list[y].description = description
    story_list.update({title: {'link' : link, 'description' : description}})
    y += 1
```